# Puppet search and replace a number using file pattern replacement

Tags: puppet

I am fairly new to puppet, I am trying to pass a TimeOut value in 'httpd.conf' file using the below code snippet in my puppet 'config.pp'

```
replace { 'Httpd Timeout':
  file        => 'httpd.conf',
  pattern     => 'TimeOut*',
  replacement => 'TimeOut 900',
}
```

But instead of replacing the code just appends the value "900" to the line like below

```
"TimeOut 900 300 "
```

How I can modify the code that the line will be like below

```
TimeOut 900
```

I am using Puppet community version 3.7

Comment: What's `replace`?  No such resource type is included with Puppet, nor is there one in Puppet's separate "stdlib" module.  You evidently have such a type, else your catalog compilations would be failing, but we cannot speak to its behavior if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: It was a custom type we  used in the config .My issue was related to the spacing and indentation.Thanks for suggestion.